# Parsing in XML in Python 2.7

Tags: xml, python-2.7, elementtree

```
import urllib
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

url = raw_input('Enter location: ')
print 'Retrieving', url
uh = urllib.urlopen(url)
data = uh.read()
print 'Retrieved',len(data),'characters'
tree = ET.fromstring(data)
lst = tree.findall('.//count')
print 'Count:', len(lst)
total = 0
for comment in tree.findall("./comments/comment"):
    total += int(comment.find('count').text)
print total
```

When i run the above code in cmd, i get the following traceback

```
C:\Users\hp1\Downloads\python\programs>xml1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\hp1\Downloads\python\programs\xml1.py", line 2, in <module>
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
File "C:\Users\hp1\Downloads\python\programs\xml.py", line 2, in <module>
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
ImportError: No module named etree.ElementTree
```

Please help, I dont understand why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

You called your file *xml.py*:

```
 "C:\Users\hp1\Downloads\python\programs\xml.py"
```

So python is looking in that file not the builtin lib xml for `etree.ElementTree`. So rename the file to something other than xml.py and remove any *xml.pyc* files in the directory